# Trouble including infoWindow into gmaps markerclusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, markerclusterer

i am having issues adding infoWindow to an existing gmaps markerclusterer project. I am aware there are similar questions but the answers i've seen haven't worked. It may be because i am fairly new to this and missing something.

Below is my code without the infoWindow. Each marker is generated from lat/long in the .jason data file.
The 'pre-attempt' code:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="data.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(34.777491, 64.5852620);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
              dataPhoto.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            icon: "images/gps.svg"
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, 
        {imagePath:'images/m'});
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      </script>

      <script>
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12846745-20']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 
      'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
      'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>

  <body>
    <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
```

The attempted but non working code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="data.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(34.777491, 64.5852620);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
          var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
              dataPhoto.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            icon: "images/gps.svg"
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
          infoWin.setContent('content here');
          infoWin.open(map, marker);
  })
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath:'images/m'});
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

    <script>
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12846745-20']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>

  <body>
    <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
```

I don't know if i am missing something obvious or if there is a conflict with the click to zoom function. To be clear i am looking to implement the infoWindow when only one device is clickable, not a cluster. Thanks for any help, i really appreciate it.

Update:

```
var data = { "count": 10785236,
 "photos": [{"photo_id": 27932, "photo_title": "Atardecer en Embalse", "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/27932", "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/27932.jpg", "longitude": -64.404945, "latitude": -32.202924, "width": 500, "height": 375, "upload_date": "25 June 2006", "owner_id": 4483, "owner_name": "Miguel Coranti", "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/4483"}
```

The var data shown above is an example from the .json file. This is one of many entries.

Comment: _To be clear i am looking to implement the infoWindow when only one device is clickable, not a cluster._ I do not understand this; Do you want to stop the cluster behaviour and use an infowindow on cluster click? Or do you want to use the infowindow when you reach the last marker in a specific location i.e. when the cluster has already opened?

Comment: Can you also include the `data.photos` to reproduce the issue more fully?

Comment: I want to use the infowindow when i reach the last marker in a location, so yes when the cluster is already open or there is only one marker present in a certain area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Inside your `for loop` a `function closure` is missing so you cannot capture infowindow objects and assign them to their relative markers, letting alone displaying their contents.

Change this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infoWin.setContent('content here');
      infoWin.open(map, marker);
})
```

For this:

```
(function(m, infoWindow, idx){
    google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function(evt) {
    infoWindow.setContent('marker ' + idx);
    infoWindow.open(map, m);

        })
 })(marker, infoWin, i);
```

To reproduce the issue, I have used 100 different lat/lon in a JSON object, as for the number of iterations in your for loop.

[Get the JSBIN with code sample here.](https://jsbin.com/qedezif/edit?html,js,output#J:L11)

Comment: Understood, works perfectly, just what i was looking for. Thank you for the help, much appreciated!